# Why it fails when getting to compile SCSS into CSS with RVM

Tags: ruby, sass, rvm

I'm attempting to compile SCSS to CSS with grunt in my Java project on Mavericks. It fails when getting to compile scss with error below:

```
Running "sass:production" (sass) task
NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

My environment is below:

- `ruby` 2.1.1 with RVM
- `Grunt`v0.4.5

**It has success when I disable RVM but I do not know why it is.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend that you run it using `--trace` so we can get a full backtrace. Then edit your question and add the full stacktrace :)

Comment: @TarynEast I run this command `$ grunt sass:production --trace` but I cannot get extra info about it. Is there any way to run this command with verbose?

Comment: hmmm, I'm not familiar with grunt - i thought you were running via rake.